# Laravel 7 Installation - npm run dev Error

Tags: laravel-7

Laravel 7 fresh Installation - npm run dev or npm run watch both are showing error also check with cross-env but not working. someone help please

```
$ npm run dev

> dev
> npm run development


> development
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

[webpack-cli] Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module.rules[10] has an unknown property 'loaders'. These properties are valid:
   object { compiler?, dependency?, descriptionData?, enforce?, exclude?, generator?, include?, issuer?, loader?, mimetype?, oneOf?, options?, parser?, realResource?, resolve?, resource?, resourceFragment?, resourceQuery?, rules?, sideEffects?, test?, type?, use? }
   -> A rule description with conditions and effects for modules.
npm ERR! code 2
npm ERR! path C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel7
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Digital Planet\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs20-12-08T17_55_32_929Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code 2
npm ERR! path C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel7
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c "npm run development"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Digital Planet\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs20-12-08T17_55_32_991Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

## Solved

1st Step:

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json yarn.lock
npm cache clear --force
npm install
```

2nd step:

package.json file add this

`"webpack": "^4.44.1",`

`npm install`